# How to get the index number of the Array[]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Write a program called GradesAverage, which prompts user for the
>   number of students, reads it from the keyboard, and saves it in an int
>   variable called numStudents. It then prompts user for the grades of
>   each of the students and saves them in an int array called grades. 
>   Your program shall check that the grade is between 0 and 100. A sample
>   session is as follow:

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student 1: 55
Enter the grade for student 2: 108
Invalid grade, try again...
Enter the grade for student 2: 56
Enter the grade for student 3: 57
The average is 56.0
```

But, in my file, this is how the program works (pay attention to the "student"):

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter the grade for student10 55
Enter the grade for student20 56
Enter the grade for student30 57
```

Can you see the 10, the 20 and 30? Instead of showing `student1`, `student2` and `student3`, it shows `student10`, `student20` and `student30`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class GradesAverage {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner miScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
        int numStudents = miScanner.nextInt();
        int numberGrades[] = new int[numStudents];
        int averageGrade = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numStudents; i++) {            
            System.out.println("Enter the grade for student" + i + numberGrades[numStudents - i]);
            int grade = miScanner.nextInt();
            averageGrade += grade;
            if (grade < 0 || grade >100) {
                System.out.println("Invalid grade, try again...");
                break;
            }
        }
        double average = averageGrade/numStudents;
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.println("Enter the grade for student" + i + numberGrades[numStudents - i]);
```

to

```
System.out.println("Enter the grade for student " + i + ":");
```

That extra **0** is outputted due to the extra `numberGrades[numStudents - i]`.

Why exactly zero ? Because `numberGrades` is an array; when initializing an array, it initializes its elements to their default types' values. *(In this case, it's an array of `int`s, so all of its elements are initialized to 0)*

**PS:** That number that you see here after the colon (in this case 55):

```
... student 1: 55
```

is actually an *input*, not a *sysout*.

Comment: More appropriately, it should be changed to: `System.out.print("Enter the grade for student " + i + ":");` to match formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("Enter the grade for student" + i + numberGrades[numStudents - i]);`

Its printing out this Enter the grade for student`i` `numberGrades[numStudents - i]`

These are not being added before printing, its printing each item.